# How to download a .plist in xcode

Tags: xcode4.2

so I'm making an iphone app, which needs to download a .plist from a server...

I know how to create and edit and do anything else with a .plist file but it just wont download for me...

I've tried using this code

```
NSMutableArray *profileArray;
profileArray = [[NSMutableArray Alloc] initWithContentsOfUrl:@"myurl.plist"];
```

but it always comes back with a (null) value, what should I do?

Thanks in advance :D

Answer (score 1):

initWithContentsOfUrl: method takes a NSURL object as a parameter. You need to create a NSURL object with your url like so:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString: @"myurl.plist"];
```

then use this to instantiate the array:

```
NSMutableArray *profileArray; profileArray = [[NSMutableArray Alloc] initWithContentsOfUrl: url];
```

Comment: Thanks, I actually worked it out myself. I'd already tried what you'd suggested. I had to save the .plist as a .php file on my server and then download it as an NSMutableArray. Works fine now